Custom conditional stop in Minizinc (Python)
I am trying to implement a way to stop a minizinc solver after a certain amount of time has passed since the last solution (I'm working with an optimization problem).
I've tried doing so using the asyncio Python library, but I couldn't get this solution to work as intended. My idea here is to start a timer each time a solution is found and, if the timeout is reached the solver is stopped and the last solution is returned.
However, in practice the solver keeps running in the background (the fzn process is still running) and no value is returned from the function until I manually kill the process from the task manager.
from minizinc import Solver, Model, Instance
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import pymzn
import os
import sys
from pymzn.aio import minizinc
import time

async def timed_solver():
    optimizer = Model("TestAsync/optim.mzn")
    solver = Solver.lookup("com.google.ortools.sat")
    instance = Instance(solver, optimizer)
    res = []
    timeout = 180
    solver_task = None
    
    async def monitor_timeout(last_solution):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            print(i)
            current = time.perf_counter()
            if current - last_solution >= timeout:
                print("Timeout reached, stopping the process.")
                solver_task.cancel()
                return None
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
                break
        return None
    
    async def getSolutions():
        timeout_task = None
        try:
            async for result in instance.solutions(optimisation_level=1, processes=8, free_search=True):
            
                if result.solution is None:
                    continue
                else:
                
                    res.append(result)
                    last_solution = time.perf_counter()
                    print("###################")
                    print(res[-1]["objective"])
                    if timeout_task:
                        timeout_task.cancel()
                    timeout_task = asyncio.create_task(monitor_timeout(last_solution))
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
            print("Timeout reached")
        return res[-1] if res else None
    
    solver_task = asyncio.create_task(getSolutions())

    try:
        await solver_task    
    
    except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
        return res[-1] if res else None
    
    return res[-1] if res else None

async def main():
    res = await timed_solver()
    if res:
        print(res)
    else:
        print("No solution found or timeout occurred.")

asyncio.run(main())


Looking at the code, I don’t see any mistakes. The idea is that the solver_task.cancel() should terminate the MiniZinc process (and therefore the solver process): https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-python/blob/develop/src/minizinc/instance.py#L451-L458. So if this is not happening this would suggest there is a bug, either in asycio processes not sending the correct signals or in some of the MiniZinc signal handling or the solver’s signal handling

A little update: I tried to run the code on another pc today and it worked fine (with some changes). I still don't know why this happend, but if I'll ever find out I'll let you know.

Second update: I tried to re-install Minizinc on all users, but I can't open  Minizinc files using the IDE, and when I try to set the default program to open .mzn files as the freshly installed IDE nothing happens.
I have also tried to set the PATH variable to the new Minizinc location, but I always get the same result.
Finally, I tried installing Minizinc on my user only, this time the IDE works as intended but in Python I get: "RuntimeWarning: MiniZinc was not found on the system. No default driver could be initialized."

MiniZinc Python uses the path, or the standard installation path as a fallback. Ensuring the minizinc executable is on the path should ensure that the python package can function as intended.
